# Custom template for Django's comments application does not display fields

Tags: django, templates, django-comments

I want to use `django.contrib.comments` in a blogging application and customize the way the form is displayed. My problem is that I can't get the fields to display although displaying the hidden fields works just fine. I had a look at the docs and compared it with the regular way of displaying forms but honestly I don't know why the following doesn't work out:

```
{% get_comment_form for comments_object as form %}
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="POST">
[…]
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for field in form.fields %}
        {{field}}
    {% endfor %}
[…]
</form>
```

The output looks like this:

```
    <form action="/comments/post/" method="POST"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="content_type" value="flatpages.flatpage" id="id_content_type" />         
            <input type="hidden" name="object_pk" value="1" id="id_object_pk" /> 
            <input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="1269522506" id="id_timestamp" />              
            <input type="hidden" name="security_hash" value="ec4…0fd" id="id_security_hash" /> 
            content_type
            object_pk
            timestamp
            security_hash
            name
            email
            url
            comment
            honeypot
        […]
    </form> 
</div>
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `{% for field in form.visible_fields %}`

`form.fields` is a dictionary where the keys are the names of the fields, and the values are the actual `form.Field()` objects.

You can also do `{% for field in form %}` which should include both hidden and visible fields.